# How can I use connection pooling in perl using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, perl

We have a Perl application that is using DBI to connect to MySQL and execute SQL statements. It creates multi connections, so I want to handle this using connection pooling and I have no idea about connection pooling.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple connections to the same database with the same DSN inside one process, you can simply replace all calls to `DBI->connect` with `DBI->connect_cached` and [the DBI will take care of reusing connections](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#connect_cached). That's not pooling, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks simbabque, Is that possible 'connection pooling' in DBI or not?

Comment: I don't know. That's why I answered an alternative.